# changing attribute value in xml via lxml python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

here is my xml:

```
<request><table attributeA="50" attributeB="1"></table>........</request>
```

how do I update attributeA's value, to have something like attributeA="456"

```
<request><table attributeA="456" attributeB="1"></table>........</request>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use etree and xpath :

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> xml = '<request><table attributeA="50" attributeB="1"></table></request>'
>>> root = etree.fromstring(xml)
>>> for el in root.xpath("//table[@attributeA]"):
...     el.attrib['attributeA'] = "456"
...
>>> print etree.tostring(root)
<request><table attributeA="456" attributeB="1"/></request>
```